# Inserting Jpeg image onto Visio drawing programmatically in C# or VBA

Tags: c#, vba, import, visio

Is there any way to insert an jpeg image onto the visio using C# or VBA?
After inserting is there a way to format it properties like width, height, position to place on the drawing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When images are imported into Visio they get wrapped up into a standard shape (with a Type property of visTypeForeignObject).

From there you're just talking to cells in the ShapeSheet. (See this post for more details on the ShapeSheet http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2007/10/just-for-starte.html)

So, you can start by using the macro recorder on Visio for this sort of thing.  Dragging an image onto the page will produce output something like this:

```
Sub Macro1()

    'Enable diagram services
    Dim DiagramServices As Integer
    DiagramServices = ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled
    ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = visServiceVersion140 + visServiceVersion150

    Dim UndoScopeID2 As Long
    UndoScopeID2 = Application.BeginUndoScope("Auto Size Page")
    Application.ActiveWindow.Page.AutoSize = False
    Application.EndUndoScope UndoScopeID2, True

    Dim UndoScopeID3 As Long
    UndoScopeID3 = Application.BeginUndoScope("Insert")
    Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Import "C:\SomeImage.jpg"
    Application.EndUndoScope UndoScopeID3, True

    ActiveWindow.DeselectAll
    ActiveWindow.Select Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(1), visSelect
    Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Move 2.129396, -0.904364

    Dim UndoScopeID4 As Long
    UndoScopeID4 = Application.BeginUndoScope("Size Object")
    Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(1).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinX).FormulaU = "46.261665987369 mm"
    Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(1).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinY).FormulaU = "212.02916285428 mm"
    Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(1).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormWidth).FormulaU = "103.47666530807 mm"
    Application.EndUndoScope UndoScopeID4, True

    Dim UndoScopeID5 As Long
    UndoScopeID5 = Application.BeginUndoScope("Size Object")
    Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(1).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinX).FormulaU = "46.261665987369 mm"
    Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(1).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormPinY).FormulaU = "185.77916321819 mm"
    Application.ActiveWindow.Page.Shapes.ItemFromID(1).CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowXFormOut, visXFormHeight).FormulaU = "73.441667394486 mm"
    Application.EndUndoScope UndoScopeID5, True

    'Restore diagram services
    ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = DiagramServices

End Sub
```

The macro recorder operates in terms of the current selection, but you don't need to.  Also, it uses SRC (Section, Row, Column) syntax instead of the simpler cell name syntax.  So a translation of the above might be something like this:

```
Sub TestAddImage()
    Call DropImage(ActivePage, "C:\SomeImage.jpg")
End Sub

Private Sub DropImage(ByRef vPag As Visio.Page, imageFile As String)

If Not vPag Is Nothing Then
    Dim newShp As Visio.Shape
    Set shpNew = vPag.Import(imageFile)
    'Set position
    shpNew.CellsU("PinX").FormulaU = "75mm"
    shpNew.CellsU("PinY").FormulaU = "175mm"
    'Set size
    shpNew.CellsU("Width").FormulaU = "100mm"
    shpNew.CellsU("Height").FormulaU = "80mm"
End If

End Sub
```

A C# version of this would look like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var vApp = MyExtensions.GetRunningVisio();
    DropImage(vApp.ActivePage, @"C:\SomeImage.jpg");
}

private void DropImage(Visio.Page vPag, string imageFile)
{
    if (vPag != null)
    {
        var shpNew = vPag.Import(imageFile);
        //Set position
        shpNew.CellsU["PinX"].FormulaU = "75mm";
        shpNew.CellsU["PinY"].FormulaU = "175mm";
        //Set size
        shpNew.CellsU["Width"].FormulaU = "100mm";
        shpNew.CellsU["Height"].FormulaU = "80mm";
    }
}
```

Note that `GetRunningVisio` is my extension method for using with LinqPad:

http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2015/12/getting-started-with-c-in-linqpad-with-visio.html

...but it's up to you how you get hold of the application object.

Comment: John, that's great ,it worked perfectly. But is there anything inbuilt to place the shape at the end of the page like shpNew.cellsu.end ? or Do I need to run a macro to find the coordinates as shown by you in "sub Macro1"?

Comment: For that you'd need to add a formula rather than a constant value to the PinX/Y cells.  For PinX: `"ThePage!PageWidth-(Width-LocPinX)"` and for PinY `"ThePage!PageHeight-(Height-LocPinY)"`.  This would set the shape the top left corner of the page.

Comment: Sorry, my Question was to place at the bottom of the page, I believe modifying formula with + would set the shape at the bottom of the page isn't it?

Comment: Hi @Puneeth, no it wouldn't, that would place it above the page.  Visio's coordinate system origin is bottom-left based so if you want to align the shape from the bottom then you don't need the page height reference and setting PinY to `"Height-LocPinY"` should give you the right result.  Have a go at doing this manually in the ShapeSheet to see the results.  Some useful links for this area might be [Shape Geometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa200965(v=office.10).aspx) and [Elements of Visio Formulas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa200961(office.10).aspx)

Comment: Sorry, just to correct my mistake above:  For PinX: `"ThePage!PageWidth-(Width-LocPinX)"` and for PinY `"ThePage!PageHeight-(Height-LocPinY)"`. This would set the shape the top **right** corner of the page.

Comment: John, My image is getting placed at the bottom of the page by this formula  shpNew.CellsU["PinY"].FormulaU ="Height-LocPinY" because as per your latter comment setting piny to the above formula should place the image at the bottom of the drawing sheet but not above the border of the drawing.

Comment: Yes, I was just correcting my mistake (comment Apr 18 at 8.22) in describing the PinX formula, which effectively says "the width of the page less half of the width of the shape".  It should have been top right, not top left, for those two formulas.

Comment: That's fine but my requirement is to place the image at the bottom not at the top. Your formula to place bottom is working fine but can you fine tune to place it above the border of the drawing form the bottom.

Comment: Hi Puneeth - I understand you want the shape on the bottom and that's why I suggested setting PinY to `"Height-LocPinY"`.  If you want to take the margin into account as well then it would be `"Height-LocPinY+ThePage!PageBottomMargin"`.  If by border you mean the shape's line weight, which sits either side of the center line, then you could try `"Height-LocPinY+(LineWeight/2)"`.  It's all a case of varying the formula to suit your needs.  Right click on the page to see the Page's ShapeSheet and various cells you can reference.  If I've missed the point then add a new question about formulas.

Comment: Sure John, Will try and if required, will start a new thread.