# Is there anyway to import an image into a Visio document using python?

Tags: python, visio, pywin32

I'm using pywin32 to manipulate Visio files automatically. Is there any way to embed an image into a Visio document using pywin32 or some other library? I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

I know the code to create a new Visio document looks something like this:

```
import win32com.client as win32
visio = win32.Dispatch("Visio.Application")
doc = visio.Documents.Add("Basic Diagram.vst")
doc.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\"username"\\Desktop\\test.vsdx")
```

But I don't know where to go from here.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Python modification of the code over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43407628/683606):

```
def dropImage(vPag, imageFile):
    if vPag is not None:
        shpNew = vPag.Import(imageFile)
        #Set position
        shpNew.CellsU("PinX").FormulaU = "75mm"
        shpNew.CellsU("PinY").FormulaU = "175mm"
        #Set size
        shpNew.CellsU("Width").FormulaU = "100mm"
        shpNew.CellsU("Height").FormulaU = "80mm"

targetPage = appVisio.ActivePage

dropImage(targetPage, r"C:\SomeImage.jpg")
```